# jQuery Backstretch issue

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to use the popular jQuery Backstretch plugin on my web page, but it's not working at all. I copied and pasted the exact same code I saw in the examples html files in the download package on the Backstretch site, changed the links sources to where they really are in my root folder, and...nothing.

I'm calling my scripts at the bottom of my html page (right before the `</body>`)

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.backstretch.js"></script>
    <script>
        $.backstretch([
          "pot-holder.jpg",
          "coffee.jpg",
          "dome.jpg"
        ], {
            fade: 750,
            duration: 4000
        });
    </script>
<script src="js/jquery.fittext.js"></script>
<script>
$("#resize_text").fitText(0.8, { minFontSize: 42, maxFontSize: '75px' });
</script>
```

(Yes, I am using FitText too).

Any idea what's wrong? There's no other jQuery script loading anywhere else on the page...and the HTML content should not matter since Backstretch is doing his magic in the `script` tag...right?

Everytime I try to integrate Backstretch, it seems to be complicated. Maybe there's something I forget to do everytime..?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Can you check the error in your console and paste it here ?

Answer (score 1):

I just found the problem.
I was using a "`background-image`" in my css file.
I thought I could use it as a fallback, but looks like you can't use both Backstretch and a `Background-image`!

Comment: You can use both! Backstretch uses an image in an extra container div. That image has a z-index value of -999(a lot) so it's always at the back. Your own div with the background image probably didn't have a z-index (thus it being 0), so the background was on top of it.